# Pass variables to chef server using Jcloud chef

Tags: chef-infra, jclouds

I am looking for a java code for passing variables to a chef server using Jcloud chef. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Have you looked at the example code on the JCloud site - https://jclouds.apache.org/guides/chef/

Comment: if you are using the latest jclouds release, you'll have to use "chef" instead of "enterprisechef", as both providers have been merged but the docs are outdated.

Comment: Please try using sample code and then let us know if you have specific issues. This question is not really appropriate for StackOverflow as there's too many possible answers, and there's not really a specific 'correct' answer.